# iOS Safari how to disable autocomplete-like functionality

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

There is a feature in ipad/iphone safari that I would like to disable, but I'm not sure what it is called so im having trouble searching for a solution.

On ipad/iphone, if I am entering some text in to an input text box, there will be a white label that appears under the textbox that has the last value I entered. This little label has an x on the left side for closing. I hope someone knows what im talking about!

I have implemented jquery ui's autocomplete on these input boxes and the label from safari is getting in the way.

Let me know if more details are needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Auto complete is an operating system's setting which the user (not the developer) decides about. The proper solution for this is, to disable any custom autocomplete logic for ios (and most probably for all android devices as well)